# How to remove group name from metro app?

Tags: windows-8.1, start-screen

After the Win8.1 April update, if you go to the start screen and open the all apps area at the bottom, modern apps now have the first letter of their name used to group them.  On my tablet this is a waste of space.  How can I get the group names disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see this now:

[image]

You can open the charms bar->Settings->"Tiles" and select  ["Show more apps in Apps view"](http://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-show-more-apps-with-small-icons-in-windows-8-1-apps-screen/)

[image]

Now the icons are smaller and you don't waste too much space.

Next to the large "Apps" string you can sort the Apps by category or usage to remove the space.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question though, I want to remove the A B C group headers, not make the tiles smaller.

Comment: there is no way to remove it. Try my workarounds or accept the letters